# How to ensure that spark job should not start until it will have all the specified minExecutor

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In my spark job I am specifying

```
--conf spark.executor.instances=42 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=42 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=50 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=40 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
```

and I don't want my spark job to start until it will have 40 executors ,but the job is starting with 2 executors only and then scaling up later

Comment: I starting shell with following config and for me it is starting with mentioned  minExecutors --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=10 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=20 --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true

Comment: Thanks Siddhartha,  did you see the case when job is running executor goes below minExecutors , do you know how maintain that the executor will never go below minexecutors

Comment: No, actually I did not observed this behaviour. Application is always maintaining the min executor numbers